# Woocommerce Checkout page input fields displaying weirdly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using wordpress 5.2.2 with understrap child theme, woocommerce plugin and Pw woocommerce gift cards plugin https://www.pimwick.com/gift-cards/

The input fields on the checkout page  display incorrectly

[image]

However when I activate the theme tweenty seventeen they display correctly

[image]

where could the problem come from?
How to get the fields to display correctly with the understrap child theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution !!

Following [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-checkout-page-problems/)

This

```css
.woocommerce-billing-fields .form-row,
.woocommerce-shipping-fields .form-row {
    display: block;
}
```

took care of the billing field and this took care of the additional information field

```css
.woocommerce-billing-fields .form-row,
.woocommerce-shipping-fields .form-row,
.woocommerce-additional-fields .form-row {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your theme has been added `display: inline-block` css to the form. Find them by doing inspect element tool from the browser and change them to `display: block`